# BSgenome data loading problem  for applying in biostrings package function 

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I installed BSgenome seems working but I am not able to load library. The following code are from  Biostrings package

```
     > require(BSgenome) 
     > require(Biostrings)      
    >    library(BSgenome.Dmelanogaster.UCSC.dm3)
    Error in library(BSgenome.Dmelanogaster.UCSC.dm3) : 
      there is no package called 'BSgenome.Dmelanogaster.UCSC.dm3'
    >   subject <- Dmelanogaster$chr3R
    Error: object 'Dmelanogaster' not found
    >   Lpattern <- "AGCTCCGAG"
    >   Rpattern <- "TTGTTCACA"
    >   matchLRPatterns(Lpattern, Rpattern, 500, subject) # 1 match
    Error in function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
      unable to find an inherited method for function "matchLRPatterns", for signature "standardGeneric"
```

I will appreciate your help. Can you try in your computer to see if this works for your? what could be potential problem.

Comment: Have you tried this procedure? http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.7/data/annotation/html/BSgenome.Dmelanogaster.UCSC.dm3.html

Comment: Thanks to Roman Lustrik the following codes works:   
            source("http://www.bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
            biocLite("BSgenome.Dmelanogaster.UCSC.dm3")        
           library(BSgenome.Dmelanogaster.UCSC.dm3)
          subject <- Dmelanogaster$chr3R
          Lpattern <- "AGCTCCGAG"
          Rpattern <- "TTGTTCACA"
          matchLRPatterns(Lpattern, Rpattern, 500, subject) # 1 match

Comment: One of the two of you should post the answer so this does not remain "unanswered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Roman Lustrik the following codes works:

```
source("bioconductor.org/biocLite.R";) 
biocLite("BSgenome.Dmelanogaster.UCSC.dm3") 
library(BSgenome.Dmelanogaster.UCSC.dm3) 
subject <- Dmelanogaster$chr3R 
Lpattern <- "AGCTCCGAG" 
Rpattern <- "TTGTTCACA" 
matchLRPatterns(Lpattern, 
Rpattern, 500, subject) # 1 match
```

Comment: You can mark this as the correct answer by clicking the gray check (which turns green) on the left below the score counter.